# DRF is not re-evaluating queryset as expected gotcha

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is a question about whether DRF is working as it should or whether it could be improved to account for this use case.

I have a simple API that returns a custom queryset like this:

```
class WorldRankingViewset(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

      queryset = Ranking.objects.world_ranking()
```

Where the custom queryset is:

```
  class RankingQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

     def world_rankings(self, rank_type="World"):
        # get most recent update
        update = RankingUpdate.objects.issued().filter(rank_type=rank_type, date__lte=TODAY).order_by("-asat", "-date").first()

        # if there is one, get all the player rankings for that update
        if update:
            return self.filter(update=update, player_id__gt=0, points__gt=0)
        else:
            return self.none()
```

In the generics.py code of DRF, the get_queryset function has this code:

```
 def get_queryset(self):
        ....

        queryset = self.queryset
        if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
            # Ensure queryset is re-evaluated on each request.
            queryset = queryset.all()
        return queryset
```

Given the comment "Ensure queryset is re-evaluated on each request" I was expecting it to do that.

However, when I run my API test, the following sequence happens.

```
 Evaluation queryset 
 Run setUpTestData() to populated data for test
 Make call to api without re-evaluating queryset
 Return no data
```

If I put a custom get_queryset code into the api then it all works as I would expect and returns test data:

```
  class WorldRankingViewset(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

        queryset = Ranking.objects.none()
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            return Ranking.objects.world_rankings()




 Run setUpTestData() to populated data for test
 Make call to api 
 Evaluate queryset 
 Return data
```

If I change my custom queryset to be a straight filter, then the original code works correctly so my question is, is this the way DRF should work and is not, is there a better way of forcing re-evaluation of the queryset other than queryset = queryset.all()?

Comment: DRF is working as it should, it __is__ reevaluating the queryset that was returned by your custom manager method, it does not call the manager method again

Comment: But unless I override the get_queryset method I don't get any data so even though the code to re-evaluate the queryset is called, it is not actually re-evaluating.

Comment: Because the `queryset` is on the class it is evaluated when your app is loaded, the queryset returned by your method will be `none()` because you have no data. This `none` queryset will be reevaluated on every request but will never return anything. You will have to use `get_queryset` whatever you do since the `world_rankings` method has a time dependent filter